# Is the closed orbit of the Van der Pol equation a stable periodic orbit?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, complex-dynamics

We  consider  the  Van der  Pol  vector  field  $$(1)  \;\;\;\;\;\;  \begin{cases}  x'=y-(x^3-x)\\ y'=-x\end{cases}$$  on  $\mathbb{R}^2.$

It  is well  known  that this  equation has  a  unique  limit  cycle $\gamma$  which is an attractor   closed orbit.  Moreover  the  eigenvalue $\lambda$ of  the derivative  of the  Poincare  return  map, corresponding to  a one  dimensional  local  section on $\gamma$,   satisfies  $0<\lambda <1$

If  we replace the  real  variable  $(x,y)$  with complex  variables $(z,w), \;\;z=x_1+ix_2,\;w=y_1+iy_2$, the  equation (1)  becomes the  following  complex  vector  field  $$(2) \;\;\;\;\;\begin{cases}  z'=w-(z^3-z)\\ w'=-z\end{cases}$$  with  the  following  real  representation  in $4$ dimensional space  $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$

$$(3) \;\;\;\;\;\begin{cases} x_1'=y_1-x_{1}^3+3x_{1}x_{2}^2+x_{1}\\ 
x_{2}'=y_{2}-3x_{1}^2x_{2}+x_{2}^3+x_2\\
y_1'=-x_1\\
y_2'=-x_2\end{cases}$$

Now  $\gamma$ is  counted  as a  periodic  orbit  of   system (3) (put  $x_{2}=y_2=0)$.  Note  that $\gamma$  is  a  non  isolated closed  orbit  of  (3). The  reason  is  that $\gamma$  lies  on  a  unique  leaf  $L$ of complex  singular  foliation  (2). On the  other  hand the  complex  vector  field (2) defines  a real  vector  field  on $L$  which  can not  possess an  isolated  closed orbit.  So  we  have  a  band  of  closed orbits  in $L$ containing  $\gamma$.

The  conclusion is  that $\{1, 1, \lambda\} $ are the three  eigenvalues  of  $DP$, the  derivative  of the Poincare  return map  $P$ defined on     a $3$  dimensional  local  section $S$  on  $\gamma $.  Because, assuming $T$ is the  period  of  $\gamma$,  we have $$Det( D\phi_{T})=e^{\int_0^T Div(X_{3})(\gamma(t))dt}=e^{\int_0^T Div(X_{1})(\gamma(t))dt}=\lambda$$
where $X_{1}, X_{3}$ are  vector fields associated with (1)  and (3), respectively  and  $\phi$ is the  flow of (3).

So we have  a  degenerate eigenvalues for the  derivative  of  Poincare  return map.In fact an eigenvalue estimate  can not help us to understand the  behavior of  solutions  of  (3) near $\gamma$.

> **Question:** With this degeneracy of eigenvalues what  can  be  said  about the  stability  of  $\gamma$?  Is  $\gamma$  a  stable  periodic  orbit  of (3), in the  sense that    there is  a  bounded  open set  containing  $\gamma$   which  is  invariant  under the positive  flow of (3)?

> What  about if  we  consider an $\epsilon$  multiplier in the  original vector  field, that is  we  consider $$(1)_{\epsilon}  \;\;\;\;\;\;  \begin{cases}  x'=y-\epsilon(x^3-x)\\ y'=-x\end{cases}$$ and corresponding $4$ dimensional  system

$$(3)_{\epsilon} \;\;\;\;\;\begin{cases} x_1'=y_1-\epsilon(x_{1}^3+3x_{1}x_{2}^2+x_{1})\\ 
x_{2}'=y_{2}-\epsilon (3x_{1}^2x_{2}+x_{2}^3+x_2)\\
y_1'=-x_1\\
y_2'=-x_2\end{cases}$$

What  can  be  said  about the  stability  of $\gamma_{\epsilon}$, the  unique  limit  cycles of  $(1)_{\epsilon}$, as  a periodic orbit  of  $(3)_{\epsilon}$?